# I can't add new options to select element using jQuery Ajax

Tags: jquery

My code:

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    html.push('<select id="options" onchange="Widjet._selectOption()">');
    html.push('</select>');

    $.ajax({
        url: hostName + 'Search/GetDataTableAsJson',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        crossDomain: "true",
        async: false, 
        success: function (data1) {
            var dt = JSON.parse(data1);
            $.each(dt, function(key, value) {
                $('#options').append($("<option></option>").attr("value", value.CityName).text(value.CityName));
```

I'm trying to populate "select" element with Json data, but the list is empty.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: cross domain ajax call works on `jsonP` datatype

Comment: Where does it fail?  Is the AJAX call being made?  What is the server's response?

Comment: When I check: var menu = $('#options'); is object, not "select" element.

Comment: I get correct data, but want to populate "select" element as well.

Comment: When I check: var menu = document.getElementById("options"); the "menu" is null.